# Close a "Get Open File Name String File" workbook

Tags: excel, vba, getopenfilename

I am trying to create some short cuts for my less than technology adept coworkers. Have basically learned VBA through reading through website this and googling and "borrowing" existing code, and so I don't have a good understanding of the why, but I can usually get to what I need. In this instance, our sales team sends over a document with the data needed to my operations teams.

I think I understand that the "As String" is just grabbing the text that is the file path to wherever they've save the document on their PC, but I'm not figuring out how to re-use that info later in the code to close it. Not a big deal if I can't get it to work, I'll just have them close the WB that opens, but would love to know how to do it.

```
Sub ImportData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Range("A2:AX22").ClearContents

Dim strFile As String

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Workbooks.Open (strFile)
  

Worksheets("xSheetFromSalesFilex").Range("A2:AX22").Copy _
Workbooks("xWorkingWB.xlsm").Worksheets("DesitnationSheet").Range("A2:AX22")


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I have gotten this code to work to the point where it opens the file that they should have saved (with a variable name, it's the name of the new account) and pastes itself into the new file they'll be using. However I can't figure out how to get the source file to close. Closest thing I found was to activate next wb and close that, but if they have multiple workbooks open this could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change this ...

```
Workbooks.Open (strFile)
```

... to this ...

```
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open (strFile)
```

... because `Workbooks.Open` returns a new `Workbook` object.

Then to close it, simply do this ...

```
objWorkbook.Close
```

... you'll need to deal with saving etc.

Comment: Thank you! That works. I think I understand the change.

Comment: If it works then please flag it as the answer.